# change PHP timestamp with date and time to date with time 00:00:00

Tags: php, timestamp

I have some timestamps with date and time in my database and I want to convert them to a timestamp with the date and set time to 00:00:00. How can I do that? I tried several code, but don't get it.

For example, I want the timestamp:

1615804200 to 1615766400
or
1619019000 to 1618963200

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php

Comment: When asking, it's always best to share your attempts. That way we can point out where you went wrong and you could learn a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [setTime() method of DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) to do that, as Sammitch has already pointed out in the comments.

Quick example:

```
// Create DateTime from Unix timestamp 1615804200.
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1615804200);
// Reset hours, minutes and seconds to zero.
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
// echo new timestamp
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

The actual timestamp you get back may depend on the [timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) that is used by your PHP environment.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps 1615766400 and 1618963200 that you expect have a time of 00:00 for the UTC time zone. Example to review:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1615766400);
//2021-03-15 00:00:00
```

For this simple case, we can subtract the remainder of the division of the seconds of a day (86400) from the timestamp .

```
$ts = 1615804200;
$tsMidnight = $ts-$ts%86400; 
echo $tsMidnight; //1615766400

$ts = 1619019000;
$tsMidnight = $ts-$ts%86400; 
echo $tsMidnight; //1618963200
```